# Recreating an XFS file system with `ftype=1`

Tags: linux, centos, docker, xfs, rhel-7

I have a CentOS 7 system where the root file system is XFS (created with `ftype=0`, the default CentOS setting at the time the system was installed). Unfortunately, the Docker `overlay2` storage driver requires that file system to have been created with `ftype=1`:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites

So now I'd like to recreate the root FS with `ftype=1`. I was thinking of doing that as follows:

1. Boot into a rescue image of some sort.
2. `xfsdump` the root FS to a remote location.
3. Recreate the root FS with `ftype=1`.
4. `xfsrestore` the root FS from the remote dump.

One thing I'm not sure about, though, is whether the `xfsdump` output carries anything related to the `ftype` setting. That is, would there be any issues doing the `xfsrestore` onto an XFS file system with a different `ftype` setting?

Or is there a better approach to solving this specific problem (that doesn't involve reinstalling the whole system, repartitioning, etc.)?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/597707/265691

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My proposed method seemed to work fine. Here's my procedure:

1. Boot into `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.iso`.
2. Open a terminal and `sudo -s`.
3. Scan for LVM volumes: `vgscan`
4. Change into the appropriate volume group (`centos` in my case): `vgchange -ay centos`
5. Scan for the logical volumes in that group: `lvscan`
6. Create a mount point for the root FS: `mkdir /mnt/root`
7. Mount the logical volume corresponding to the root FS: `mount /dev/centos/root /mnt/root`
8. Dump to remote host: `xfsdump -J - /mnt/root | ssh <host> 'cat >/data/rootfs.dump'`
9. Unmount the root FS: `umount /mnt/root`
10. Recreate the root FS: `mkfs.xfs -f -n ftype=1 /dev/centos/root`
11. Mount the recreated root FS: `mount /dev/centos/root /mnt/root`
12. Restore from remote host: `ssh <host> 'cat /data/rootfs.dump' | xfsrestore -J - /mnt/root`
13. Reboot. Everything should be as it was before, except `xfs_info /` should now show `ftype=1`.

Note: My `xfsdump` call resulted in a number of warnings of the form

```
xfsdump: WARNING: failed to get bulkstat information for inode 10485897
```

According to someone who appears to be an XFS developer ([link](https://web.archive.org/web/20240122213501/https://linux-xfs.oss.sgi.narkive.com/VJ7ZBF9i/xfs-and-lvm-snapshots#post7)):

> They can be ignored - they are inodes that were previously unlinked,
> but are still partially there on the snapshot volume, and visible  to
> the by-handle interfaces that xfsdump is using to extract all of  the
> inodes in the snapshot.

Comment: Don't forget to check your dracut initramfs and/or GRUB config for UUID references: `mkfs.xfs` generates a new UUID, and grub/initramfs will not be able to find it with the old reference. Rebuild if needed!

Comment: @AlexMazzariol I didn't run into this issue, and I'm kind of curious why. Is your install pretty standard? Anyway, I guess it might be a good idea to use [`xfs_admin`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_admin) to get (`-u`) the UUID before recreating, and if needed, set (`-U`) the UUID in the recreated FS back to the original.

Comment: Yes, tried on both LVM and plain partitioning, plain CentOS installation. In both cases on `/etc/fstab` the partitions are identified by UUID, and dracut fails to recognize the root after the `mkfs.xfs`; when not using LVM also GRUB passed the old UUIDs as `root=` to the kernel. Can be solved by remaking grub-options and dracut, or as you said, by restoring the previous UUID with `xfs_admin`.

Comment: I can independently confirm this procedure works on Rhel7 and is safe to use. I saved and restored the uuid with xfs_admin just in case. I used a local usb drive rather than ssh myself and save and restore was pretty quick.

Comment: Thanks for working out the detailed procedure,  but why would you do this for Docker,  since when you switch storage drivers you lose all existing containers/images installed anyway (under ./devicemapper they will not be visible in the new overlay2 mode which will have its own subdir ./overlay2)?

Comment: @RichK. Your Docker state likely won't be too hard to recreate, but if your Docker host is also used for other things, recreating all that configuration could be painful.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this worked for me too! Thank you. I pulled the original UUID using `xfs_admin -u /dev/centos/root` after step 5.   I then used `xfs_admin -U UUID /dev/centos/root` after step 10.  One additional step I did was after step 11, I set selinux to permissive (`setenforce 0`) as my first attempt produced selinux warnings or errors. I don't know if this was necessary but the errors went away.

Comment: Consider editing the larger answer rather than "confirming" as "me too" answers can often get voted to be deleted. If you intend this to stand alone as a complete answer - please be sure to edit all the information needed or explain a bit why / how this differs from the accepted answer.